# Convert prototype to ES6 Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web-component, preact

Trying to convert a js "class" written using prototypes into an ES6 class, the new version runs without errors but does not display any content in the DOM whereas the old version does.

The specifics of how the class works shouldn't be important, however, I'm trying to implement a custom web component in preact.

```
// common imports for completeness
import { h, render, FunctionComponent, VNode } from "preact";
```

```
// old version: working ✅

function connectedCallback() {
  this._vdom = toVdom(this, this._vdomComponent);
  render(this._vdom, this._root);
}

function disconnectedCallback() {
  render((this._vdom = null), this._root);
}

function toVdom(element: HTMLElement, nodeName?: FunctionComponent<any>) {
  if (element.nodeType === 3) return element.data;
  if (element.nodeType !== 1) return null;
  const children = Array.from(element.childNodes).reverse().map(cn => toVdom(cn));
  return h(nodeName || element.nodeName.toLowerCase(), {}, children);
}

function createCustomElement(Component: FunctionComponent<any>) {
  function PreactElement() {
    const inst = Reflect.construct(HTMLElement, [], PreactElement);
    inst._vdomComponent = Component;
    inst._root = document.body;
    return inst;
  }
  PreactElement.prototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);
  PreactElement.prototype.constructor = PreactElement;
  PreactElement.prototype.connectedCallback = connectedCallback;
  PreactElement.prototype.detachedCallback = disconnectedCallback;

  return PreactElement;
}
```

```
// new version: not working ❌

const createCustomElement = (Component: FunctionComponent<any>) => {
  return class PreactElement extends HTMLElement {
    private readonly _vdomComponent = Component;
    private readonly _root = document.body;
    private _vdom: VNode<any> | null = null;

    private static toVdom = (element: HTMLElement, nodeName?: FunctionComponent<any>) => {
      if (element.nodeType === 3) return element.data;
      if (element.nodeType !== 1) return null;
      const children = Array.from(element.childNodes).reverse().map(cn => PreactElement.toVdom(cn));
      return h(nodeName || element.nodeName.toLowerCase(), {}, children);
    }

    connectedCallback = () => {
      this._vdom = PreactElement.toVdom(this, this._vdomComponent);
      render(this._vdom, this._root);
    }

    disconnectedCallback = () => {
      render((this._vdom = null), this._root);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Time to debug! Add breakpoints to the methods (or `console.log()` calls if your environment doesn't support that). Do all the methods you expect to be called actually get called? Do all variables have the expected values. Add the same debugging to the old version of the code, what's different?

Comment: "the new version runs with errors..." Please show them.

Comment: @MikeM apologies that was a type "without" error.

Comment: @AlexWayne thanks, I'm currently trying that. Was wondering if there's something obvious regarding "this" in JS that I'm missing.

Comment: If there was, typescript _should_ catch it. But you can verify it by adding `console.log('myMethodName:this', this)` to each method and see if it looks right.

Comment: Don't know if this is the source of your problem but in the working/prototype version there's a "detachedCallback" method, whereas your class version has "disconnectedCallback".

Comment: Thanks @AlexWayne, I found the source of the issue. It turns out that arrow functions on a class don't implement a base class' method. I had to change connectedCallback and disconnectedCallback to regular class functions.

Comment: @rayhatfield Thanks, I'll look up the documentation on that. It wasn't the issue case. But I'll be good to have the interface right.

Answer (score 1):

```
const createCustomElement = (Component: FunctionComponent<any>) => {
  return class PreactElement extends HTMLElement {
    private readonly _vdomComponent = Component;
    private readonly _root = document.body;
    private _vdom: VNode<any> | null = null;

    private static toVdom = (element: HTMLElement, nodeName?: FunctionComponent<any>) => {
      if (element.nodeType === 3) return element.data;
      if (element.nodeType !== 1) return null;
      const children = Array.from(element.childNodes).reverse().map(cn => PreactElement.toVdom(cn));
      return h(nodeName || element.nodeName.toLowerCase(), {}, children);
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      this._vdom = PreactElement.toVdom(this, this._vdomComponent);
      render(this._vdom, this._root);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
      render((this._vdom = null), this._root);
    }
  };
};
```